# How to extract values that correspond to numbers in files's names?

Tags: r

I have one file (matrix) `time` that its  values are hours from 0 to 23. This file can be read as:

```
  conne1 <- file("/dat/file_time.bin","rb")
  file_time<- readBin(conne1, numeric(), size=4,  n=1000*500, signed=TRUE)
```

Now I have other `24 files` that have the same dim as  `time`  and can be read exactly as `time`:

```
dir1=list.files("/data/files", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(dir1)){
readBin(dir1[i], numeric(), size = 4 ,n = 1000 * 500 , signed = T)
……………}
```

These 24 files are named like this:

```
File1_00.bin;File1_01.bin;.....Until......File1_23.bin
```

What I need is just to start reading values in `time` and ,for example, if the value is 12 in `time`, go to the file named File1_12.img in `dir1`and extract the corresponding value and so on. At the end I have one file like`time` but it has corresponding values from the 24 files.

Comment: isn't `dir1` a vector of sorted file names which will be in order 0:23 so you don't really need to match anything?

Comment: `sub("File1_(\\d{2})\\.bin", "\\1", "File1_00.bin")` will extract the 2 digits. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: @CathG I try to explain it differently. these 24 files are hourly measurements of soil temperature. Let’s take one file of them,for example File1_01.bin contains the soil temperature values that were obtained at 01:00 clock. And similarly for File1_22.bin which contains the values that were obtained at 22:00 clock etc.,. Now I have only one file_time which contains the time desired (varies from 00 to 23) and my task is to find all soil temperature values that correspond to these times from dir1.

Comment: I don't understand how your "file1_xx.bin" can have the same dim as file_time

Comment: `file1_xx.bin` is `a matrix 1000 * 500`  and `file_time` is `a matrix 1000 * 500` too.

Comment: values in `file_time` are  (0 to 23) while values in `file1_xx.bin` are soil temperature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce, but I'd try the following, assuming that I understood what you want:

```
 #read all the files and store in a matrix
 allContent<-do.call(cbind,lapply(dir1,
                           function(x) readBin(x, numeric(), size = 4 ,n = 1000 * 500 , signed = T)))
 #subset allContent to get the desired values
 allContent[cbind(1:(1000*500),file_time+1)]
```

To make a test:

```
 #create the file time sampling randomly between 0 and 23
 set.seed(1234)
 n<-1383 * 586
 file_time<-runif(n,0,23)
 #creating an n x 24 matrix with values between 0 and 9999
 allContent<-matrix(runif(n*24,0,9999),ncol=24)
 #subsetting
 allContent[cbind(1:n, file_time + 1)]
```

Just the last edit to explain last line. You can subset a `matrix` by providing a two-column matrix in which each row indicates the element to take. In my line, the `cbind(1:n, file_time + 1)` forms a matrix whose first row is made by 1 and the first value of `file_time`, the second by 2 and the second value of `file_time` and so on. Since each column of `allContent` is the content of the i-th file, I'm saying that the first value of the output must be the first value of the `file_time[1]`th column and so on.

If I wasn't clear enough, you can chech `?"["`, section `Matrices and arrays`, the third form of indexing.

Comment: Thanks @nicola. I try to explain it differently. these 24 files are hourly measurements of soil temperature. Let’s take one file of them,for example `File1_01.bin` contains the soil temperature values that were obtained at 01:00 clock. And similarly for `File1_22.bin` which contains the values that were obtained at 22:00 clock etc.,. Now I have only one `file_time` which contains the time desired (varies from 00 to 23) and my task is to find all soil temperature values that correspond to these times from `dir1`.

Comment: Each file has 1000*500 hourly soil measurements for the globe (so it is a matrix represents the globe),there is soil temperature for each pixel(lat/long). we want to extract soil temperature just for certain times,for the globe, that available in our `file_time`. If we take a pixel, in `file_time`, `950 320`, this pixel has value of 13. now find soil temperature for this pixel?. we first find the corresponding time which is `File1_13.bin` and then just extract the soil temperate value for this pixel `950 320` !

Comment: thanks once again. is not a big file and all files are the same and only values inside them change so you can copy the file and use it as a file_time. The idea is how to do it? in your answer, I wonder how you subset without searching the file that correspond to the time in the files names?.

Comment: numbers are not problem. My problem is how to find the file (based on its file name) that has the same number(or close to) of a pixel in `file_time` and then extract the soil temperature value for the corresponding pixel?

Comment: Ah sorry. yes file_time is made of numbers in the 0-23 range

Comment: `> str(allContent)
 num [1:810438, 1:24] 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 ...` . pls note that `n = 1383 586`

Comment: `str(file_time) num [1:810438]12.50 13.00 22.05 ...`   `> range(file_time)
[1] 0       23`

Comment: they are float. `> allContent[cbind(1:(1383*586),file_time+1)]
Error in allContent[cbind(1:(1383 * 586), file_time + 1)] : 
  subscript out of bounds`. post your test?

Comment: Thanks. Can you pls explain a bit what this `res=allContent[cbind(1:n, file_time + 1)]` does exactly? I do not understand the logic here?

Comment: @ nicola. would you explain so that I accept your answer?